# Как получать среднее двух кадров с камеры OpenCV Python?

Tags: python, opencv

При получении изображения с камеры нам каждый раз отображается новый frame. Но, как каждый раз получать среднее изображение нового фрейма и предыдущего? Вариант с методом **mean** в **numpy** годится, но проблема в том, что я не могу все это запустить в бесконечном цикле. Прошу знающих внести дополнения в коде, чтобы выводились наложенные друг на друга 2 изображения в бесконечном цикле.

Учитывая комментарии людей, попробую объяснить более подробно. На первой итерации цикла **while** мы получаем **frame1** и выводим его на экран. На второй итерации камера порождает нам **frame2**. Так вот на второй итерации нужно подвести **frame1** для того, чтобы объединившись с **frame2** прородился результат этой операции **frame3**, который уже выведется на экран. (Т.е. На первой итерации выводится на экран **frame1**, а на второй уже **frame3**)
Зачем это нужно? Конечно, для обычной вэбки это совершенно ни к чему. Но для научного оборудования такое полезно.

***main.py***

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

class Camera1():
    def __init__(self):
        super(Camera1, self).__init__()
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.previousFrame = None

    def run(self):
        while(True):
            ret, frame = self.cap.read()
            if self.previousFrame is not None:
                meanFrame = [frame, self.previousFrame]
            else:
                self.previousFrame = frame
                meanFrame = [frame, self.previousFrame]
            composicion = np.mean(meanFrame, 0)
            cv2.imshow('Video', composicion)
            self.previousFrame = composicion
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

        self.cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = Camera1()
    c.run()
```

Comment: Что вы подрозумеваете под средним?

Comment: Наложить друг на друга?

Comment: Вариант с методом **mean** в **numpy** годится, но проблема в том, что я не могу все это запустить в бесконечном цикле. Прошу знающих внести дополнения в коде, чтобы выводились наложенные друг на друга 2 изображения в бесконечном цикле.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что подразумевается под новым кадром?  самый последний полученный кадр? И нужно получить промежуточный кадр между предпоследним и последним?

Comment: какое на... среднее между двумя потенциально не связаными изображениями? (при быстром движении) и нафига такая ересь? почему не тремя?

Comment: Учитывая комментарии людей, попробую объяснить более подробно. На первой итерации цикла while мы получаем frame1 и выводим его на экран. На второй итерации камера порождает нам frame2. Так вот на второй итерации нужно подвести frame1 для того, чтобы объединившись с frame2 прородился результат этой операции frame3, который уже выведется на экран. (Т.е. На первой итерации выводится на экран frame1, а на второй уже frame3)
Зачем это нужно? Конечно, для обычной вэбки это совершенно ни к чему. Но для научного оборудования такое полезно.

Comment: @ganz шум давить на статической картинке, траекторию быстрой цели нарисовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вполне годное решение. Еще добавил стабилизацию. Операция сложения кадров никак не повлияла на производительность, что очень хорошо. Надеюсь, кому-то пригодится.

***main.py***

```
import cv2
from vidgear.gears import CamGear
import time

class Camera1():
    def __init__(self):
        super(Camera1, self).__init__()
        self.previousFrame = None

    def run(self):
        stream = CamGear(source=0).start()

        while(True):
            #start_time = time.time()
            frame = stream.read()
            if self.previousFrame is not None:
                composicion = cv2.addWeighted(frame, 0.5, self.previousFrame, 0.5, 0.0)
            else:
                self.previousFrame = frame
                composicion = cv2.addWeighted(frame, 0.5, self.previousFrame, 0.5, 0.0)
            cv2.imshow('Video', composicion)
            self.previousFrame = composicion
            #end_time = time.time()
            #print("Время выполнения: ", end_time - start_time)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

        cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = Camera1()
    c.run()
```